# What are the pros and cons of slow cuts versus fast cuts?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, cutting

**My Background**

I completed a 4 month long clean bulk a couple of weeks ago. Over those 4 months I put on 10lbs and my lifts went up significantly. I followed a keto-paleo diet (unconventional for bulking I know) and 6 day push, pull, legs split.

---

Now I want to start a cut to lean out, while still preserving as much muscle mass and strength as possible. Based on my background and goals, should I do a slow cut (200-300 calorie deficit daily) or a fast cut (1000+ calories)? And why?

Answer (score 4):

*To answer your question directly, there is indeed a huge difference between fast cuts and slow cuts.* The first point I'm making will point you to a very clear study about it.
To add more on it, here is a bit more detailed answer.

There are multiple factors to consider when planning a diet:

**I Rate of weight loss**

[Studies have shown](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21558571) that there seem to be an optimal threshold with which fat loss was optimal in regards to lean body mass. It is said that 0.7% of body weight loss a week is optimal.

**II Protein intake**

[According to this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28166780), a combination of high protein diet and resistance training is the best way to conserve muscle when trying to lose weight. 
[A diet high in protein is key during prolonged weight loss](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28166780)

**III Sleep**

Sleep is a huge factor. [This article](https://news.uchicago.edu/article/2010/10/03/sleep-loss-limits-fat-loss-study-finds) is about a study where they compared the rate of fat loss between people sleeping 5.30 hours a night versus 7.30 while being on the same caloric intake. They found a tremendous difference between the two, in favor of the more sleep group.

**IV Training**

Multiple styles of training exist. [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23019316) argues that Aerobic training is the best regarding weight loss while resistance training is optimal for conserving muscle mass.

I hope this helped !

Comment: Great answer, [here] is a question that looks at effect of rapid weight loss on basal metabolic rate.